# How to Assign MAP argument in JavaScript (JSNI) in GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

Is there any way to assign Map in JavaScript (JSNI) which are passed from Java Code and iterate,see the Below Example

*Map Holds key,value Pair:*

```
private Map<String,String> map;
public Map<String,String> getMapValue(){
return map;
}
```

*Calling JSNI:*

```
cellTableTemp(getMapValue());
```

*JSNI Method:*

```
public static native void cellTableTemp(Map<String,String> map)/*-{
//how to iterate map here

}-*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
public static native void cellTableTemp(Map<String,String> map)/*-{

  var keys = map@java.util.Map::keySet()();

  for (var k: keys) {
    // do something 
  }

}-*/;
```